# Dynamically created checkboxes using ajax from sql result set

Tags: html, sql, ajax, dynamic, checkbox

I am looking to use ajax to dynamically create checkboxes each time you change your selection from a `<select>` tag, see the below screenshot for a section of the **form** that is relevant:

[image: snippet]

**NOTE:** The checkboxes under "**Queues**" should be dynamic.

At the moment, when you change the value for **Team** it grabs the team name (in this case "Test"), then using ajax (POST) it returns the Manager name for that team.

What I want it to do is look up another table that has a list of the "queues" associated with each team; I am going to add an "onchange" attribute in the tags for the "**Manager Name**" field.

Below is the code I'm currently using to accomplish the **Team** => **Manager Name** dynamic filling:

```
<script>
        window.onload = function() {
            getManager($("#team").val());       
        }

        function getManager(team) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getManager.php",
                data: {team:team}
            }).done(function( manager ) {
                $("#manager_name").val(manager);
            });
        }
</script>
```

And here is the `getManager.php` file that it uses:

```
<?php

require("../../database/db.php");

$mysqli = new db("nab_reporting");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$team=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['team']);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT manager_name FROM team WHERE teamname = '".$team."'");

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['manager_name'];

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Keeping in mind that the above works; I now need a way to use the `onchange` attribute of the **Manager Name** field that will use ajax (similar to above), passing another php page the value that is currently in the field (in this case Kane Charles) and will return a result set (array or JSON maybe?) containing a list of all queues in the database that match up with that Team name.

Below is the html code for each of the different bits:

**TEAM**

```
<select name="team" id="team" required="required" onchange="getManager(this.value)">
               <?php 
                    include(__DIR__ . "/../../database/db.php");
                    $db = new db("nab_reporting");
                    $result = $db->query("SELECT teamname FROM team");
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "
                        <option value=\"" . $row['teamname'] . "\">" . $row['teamname'] . "</option>
                        ";
                    }
                    $db->close();
                 ?>
</select>
```

**MANAGER NAME**

```
<input type="text" name="manager_name" id="manager_name" required="required" onchange="getQueues(this.value)">
```

**QUEUES**

```
<label>
    Queues
</label>
<div id="queue_options">
    <!-- queues dynamically created here -->
</div>
```

I need the contents of **`queue-options`** to be erased and reset to only the queues associated with the current team; I haven't done a great deal with ajax, hence why I'm posting on here.

Comment: There is no <selection> tag in HTML

Comment: My bad, I meant `<select>` I will edit my answer accordingly. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well I looked over your question and from what I see. You want to get the queues through ajax, but you removed the code that fetches the queues from your question.

Comment: I haven't written it yet @John, that's what I'm not sure of. See when it grabs the manager name, it is only returning one result; I need it to return a set of results (array or JSON I'd say) containing a list of all the queues for that team. That's what I'm not sure on how to do

Comment: added as an answer to have formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This revision should match what you are asking about

PHP

```
// make an array to hold the queues
$data = Array();

// Fetch the rows of all the queues
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM the_queue_table WHERE manager='" . $_GET["manager"] . "'");

// loop through all the rows and push the queues into the data array
while(($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) !== false)
{
    array_push($data, $row->queue);
}

// return the data array as a json object
echo json_encode($data);
```

JavaScript

```
// get the page and send the manager name to filter with
$.get("file.php?manager=" + managerName, function(page)
{
    // parse the json into an object
    var data = $.parseJSON(page);

    // remove existing checkboxes
    $("#queue_options").children().remove();

    // add checkboxes to the div
    for (var item in data){
        $("#queue_options").append("<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"" + item + "\" />" + item + "<br />");
    }
});
```